# Поиск и вывод уровня вложенных элементов ul в Html с помощью beatiful soup 4 Python

Tags: html, python

пытаюсь пропарсить сайт с информацией по музыкальным жанрам [Список жанров музыки](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8).
Сайт на котором лежит информация [textPage](https://db0nus869y26v.cloudfront.net/ru/%25D0%25A1%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA_%25D0%25B6%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2_%25D1%258D%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B9_%25D0%25BC%25D1%2583%25D0%25B7%25D1%258B%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8?rev=1592232669763)
Проблема в том, что не могу понять как вывести уровень вложенных элементов( иерархически), а не последовательным списком

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(textPage, 'lxml')
for ul in soup('ul'):
print(ul.text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информация об каждом отдельно подтипе жанра содержится в теге `<li>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```
// get requests and saving to soup
types = soup.find_all("li")
for type in types:
   name = type.find("a").get_text()\
   sub_types = type.find_all("a")[1:]
   sub_names = []
   for st in sub_types:
      sub_names.append(st.get_text())
```

Так же на старнице есть немного жанров без ссылки. Их можно добавить вручную (их там оч мало) или искать по тегу `li` вложеному в `ul`